# rails s error os x 10.8.4 rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, osx-mountain-lion

I am just installing ruby / rails / gems ect.  I installed rvm and I received many errors similar to this post, not sure if it is related.  I believe I resolved the issues by installing ruby docs.

https://gist.github.com/klynton/5864062#file-rails-4-0-0-install-L1

After installing everything I was able to create my project with the following command, which appeared successful

```
rails new simple_cms -d mysql
```

I then ran the following command and received the following errors,

```
jg$ rails s
/Users/jgr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `require': dlopen(/Users/jgr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/jg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/jg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Users/jg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /Users/jg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/jg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /Users/jg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /Users/jgr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /Users/jg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/jg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/jg/Documents/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Users/jg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/jg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from /Users/jg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3):

I had experienced a similar issue.  Adding a symlink similar to the following worked for me:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Please give this a try.